# Function that returns all indexes that do not overlap - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an array like so:

```json
[
    {
        indexes: [1, 3, 5, 8],
        length: 2
    }, 
    {
        indexes: [2, 4, 6, 7],
        length: 1
    }
]
```

I am using this to split a string (and many other similar ones):

```
matatatatt
```

I am trying to split it by the array `['at', 't']`, which should return something like this in the future:

```
['m', 'at', 'at', 'at', 'at', 't']
```

This is the code I currently have:

```js
function splitVars (eq, vars) {
        let splitted = eq.split("");
        let locs = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            let variable = vars[i];

            let found = locations(variable, eq)

            locs.push({
                indexes: found,
                variable: variable,
                varLength: variable.length
            })
        }

        return locs;
    }

    function locations(substring, string){
        var a=[],
            i=-1;
        while((i = string.indexOf(substring, i + 1)) >= 0) a.push(i);
        return a;
    }        

console.log(splitVars('wmtmtmtt', ['mt', 't']));
```

However, back to my question.
As you can tell, because the length of the second string is one, it is picking up the one letter in the first indexes that is the same. Because the indexes `[2, 4, 6]` are overlapping with the first indexes, I would like to remove them.

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You talk about strings but there is nothing in the question that explains how the string and indexes are related. Further more it is not clear why those indexes do overlap.

Comment: @Pac0 I am not sure if it matters for what I am doing

Comment: this post is so confusing bro i suugest you to do some research first then try and then post here if you stuck anywhere

Comment: please add what you have and what you want to get, beside the code, you tried.

Comment: @t.niese thanks for commenting! My eventual goal is to split a string into a substring using these arrays, as I tried to convey by talking about the string I am given, the array I am using to break it up, and the result I want. Then I talk about my issue-- the fact that the indexes overlap so when I split the string, it sometimes cuts in the middle of a string that I wanted. For example: if I have the string "ma", and want to cut the string using this array: `['ma', 'a']`. In this case, nothing should happen, the "ma" should override the "a". This doesn't happen. Sorry if this was confusing.

Comment: @NinaScholz ok, I will. Thanks.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have added it.